# BigQuery check for array overlap

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

So I'm writing a BigQuery query and basically just need to be able to check if any of a number of strings are present as elements in one of the columns of the table, where the cared-about column itself contains arrays of strings. Just for context, I'm writing the query as part of a little automated Python job and am using standard SQL.

I couldn't find anything that would explicitly check for array inclusion here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators

So I came up with a solution that employs a pretty hacky regex, specifically:

```
...other query stuff...

WHERE
    REGEXP_CONTAINS((LOWER(ARRAY_TO_STRING(column, '-'))), r"({joined_string})")
```

...where  `column` is the column I care about in the table, and `joined_string` is a long string composed of all the strings I need to check for joined by `|` (where `|` serves as the regex OR operator).

Does there exist some kind of built-in functionality in BigQuery standard SQL that allows one to do this more sanely?

Comment: please clarify - is `column` a repeated field of strings?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant yes it is, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: i guessed it already :o) - see my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are two examples.

First assuming you have your strings in another table  `strings`

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, ['abc', 'def', 'xyz'] AS column UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ['123', '456', '789'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, ['135', '246', '369'] 
),
strings AS (
  SELECT 'abc' AS str UNION ALL
  SELECT '123' UNION ALL
  SELECT '456'
)
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(column) AS col JOIN strings ON col = str) > 0
```

You can add  below to `SELECT` list if you need to see how many strings are matching

```sql
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(column) AS col JOIN strings ON col = str) AS cnt
```

Second example assumes you have list of strings packed in Array

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, ['abc', 'def', 'xyz'] AS column UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ['123', '456', '789'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, ['135', '246', '369'] 
),
strings AS (
  SELECT ['abc', 'def', '456'] AS strs
)
SELECT yourTable.*
FROM yourTable, strings
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(column) AS col JOIN UNNEST(strs) AS str ON col = str) > 0
```

Same as in first example  - you can add below to `SELECT` list to see matches count

```sql
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(column) AS col JOIN UNNEST(strs) AS str ON col = str) AS cnt
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this would do the trick - my `strings` is really just an array I'm formatting into the text of the query from within Python but I think the second method would still work. Seemed like BigQuery would have some dedicated function for this but I guess no such luck.